# If I have a weird IP address, is that a sign I've been hacked?

Tags: security, ip

My roommates and I are connected to the internet through a switch. Their computers both have IP addresses that start with 81, according to [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/). The site says that my IP address starts with 212. My roommate is scaring me, saying that this means my internet usage is being "re-routed" and monitored by someone malicious.

I don't know anything about how networking works and I can't find anything about this online. So could someone please tell me if it's a dangerous sign that my computer has an IP address in a completely different range from the other two computers behind the switch?

Possibly relevant is that the website's lookup service does display the "host name" as my broadband company. Sorry if I'm not providing the necessary information but I have no clue how all this works.

Comment: What is your IP, what is the IP of the roommates? Why is yours suspicious and not theirs? Do you check the right interface? How do you check your IP? ~they theirs? Did you do a `whois 212.x.y.z` and `whois 81.a.b.c`? Why not? ;)

Comment: @user unknown 1) I don't want to give out the full address. 2) Because mine is completely different from theirs. 3) I don't understand what "right interface" means. 4) We all used whatismyip.com. 5) Isn't the IP lookup I did the same as a whois?

Comment: 1) Why? Do you believe they're magic? 2) But theirs is different from yours too! 3) eth0, eth1, ppp0, wlan0 or localhost, ts. 4) Thanks. 5) I don't know what you used - it shows up your ISP for both adresses? Then: What's the problem? 6) (overall): Why should a hacker change your IP? What's his benefit?

Comment: @user unknown The reason he is worried is that if they are all using the same Internet connection, you would expect the external IP to be the same. Also, a whois is for domain names, he would want to do an "nslookup 212.x.x.x."

Comment: Yes, KCotreau, I understand that, but why is `his` IP suspicious, and not the IPs of his friends?

Comment: @blue sand - Download & burn a Linux live-cd (Ubuntu should work), and do your test again with everybody's computer. If anybody's IP changes, start looking there, since you know that the live-cd is a fixed configursation, apart from any automatic configuration at boot time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some trojans set your browsers to use proxies.  Then all traffic is forwarded through some random server in another country.  You should be able to tell for sure in a few easy steps:

1. Check to see if whatever browser you are using has a proxy setting. [firefox](http://www.hsl.virginia.edu/services/computing/FirefoxProxySetUp.cfm), [IE and Chrome](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-proxy-settings-in-Internet-Explorer)
2. Do a virus scan with one of the modern virus scan packages that has been fully updated
3. Look up both IPs in [ARIN(US)](https://www.arin.net/) or [RIPE(Europe)](http://www.db.ripe.net/whois/) to see who owns them.  If they are not assigned to your ISP, then something is fishy.

Answer (score 2):

No, it could mean that you're ISP is using a transparent proxy like mine does - most ip detection sites and methods break down when that happens - in most cases for me, the two ip addresses detected by checkip (use [this](http://checkip.dyndns.com/) and [this](http://checkip.dyndns.com:8245/) )are different - the first one is regular ip address detection, and the second works behind, well almost anything ([via dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/dyndns.html#readme-proxy))

You may also have problems with sites that need to know your ip address to work.

Good news is, its probably not hacking. Bad news is, its quite often an utter pain since it breaks quite a few things.

Answer (score 1):

No, it could mean that your ISP has multiple network blocks on the same interface. The network blocks are often in different regions. You can check up your IP location from GeoIP.